# No convergence in Discrete metric - why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

If I have a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := (\cfrac{1}{n},\cfrac{1}{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Then why isn't there convergence with respect to the Discrete metric?

for a discrete metric, the distance between $x = \cfrac{1}{n} = y = $ should be $0$ ?

Comment: Your metrics in this case should be a function $d:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I just realised the distance metric is: $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_{disc}(x_n,(0,0))$ not between $x$ and $y$

Comment: It’s worth recognizing that if $d$ is the discrete metric on a set $X$, then a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ is convergent if and only if it’s eventually constant, i.e., if and only if there are an $x\in X$ and $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $m\ge n$. Of course in that case it converges to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric is a function from $\Bbb{R}^2\times \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^{+}$. So $$d\left((\frac1n,\frac1n),(0,0)\right)=1$$

Comment: good man, solid answer